# Creating load balancer failed Reason: Default VPC not found

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, deployment, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

i m trying to deploy my app spring boot to aws elastic beanstalk , but i got these errors:

[image]

Comment: Do you have a default VPC? Please add details on what you checked and the what you found.

Answer (score 31):

Some AWS service uses the Default VPC, for some reason you don't have it in your region (according to the image is Oregon).

Fortunately now is really easy to recover your default VPC, go to your VPC Dashboard and click on "Your VPCs", then click button "Actions" and then "Create Default VPC".

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/default-vpc.html#create-default-vpc

Answer (score 0):

here are my observations please have a look below,

Cause: (If there is no default VPC exist in you current region of the aws account)
**AND**
((You did'nt specify the network related details either via console or via
saved configuration)
**OR**
(If you specified the network related details via "saved configuration" but
from backend the aws changed the saved configuration **format**))

Resolution: (**Create default VPC**)
**OR**
(Specify the **Network related details in ELasticBeanstalk Console**)
**OR**
(Change the **Saved Configuration to the latest format of Aws**)
Note: Network related details means here: VPC, Subnet ..etc

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).